# unable to click on the element Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

'm not able to click on the element. The code without letting me to see the Exception jumping to Except Block. In Except block also first 2 lines after flow control is going to for c in range(sheet.ncols):
    for r in range(sheet.nrows): Here not able to find or click on the xpath. And the code output is 
Process finished with exit code 0

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import xlrd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('url')
driver.switch_to.frame('m')
emailElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/input')

# emailElem=browser.find_element_by_id('l')
# emailElem=browser.find_element_by_name("id")
emailElem.send_keys('sf@df.com')
# time.sleep(5)
passwordElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/p[1]/input')
passwordElem.send_keys('#####')

passwd=passwordElem.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/p[2]/input').click()
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame('topFrame')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.menu > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(7) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').click()#Reports
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame('ST_mainFrame')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.menu_row:nth-child(16) > span:nth-child(3) > label:nth-child(2)').click() #FTO


driver.switch_to.frame('fto_details')
time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html body table tbody tr td form table tbody tr td a img').click()#search





path = r'C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Python\WebScraping\Book2.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)


"""def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False

    return True
    """
for c in range(sheet.ncols):
    for r in range(sheet.nrows):
        st = (sheet.cell_value(r, c))
        try:
            if st == float(st):
                st_string = str(int(st))



                xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]"
                #cont = 0
                if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click() #Here new window will open
                    handles = driver.window_handles
                    h = len(handles)#h=2

                    #print(handles)
                    for handle in range(1,h):
                    #for handle in range(h):

                        driver.switch_to.window(handles[handle])
                        #driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/input').click()
                        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.t2').click()
                        #time.sleep(2)
                        #driver.close()

                        lst_window = driver.window_handles
                        h2 = len(lst_window) #h2=2
                        def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
                            try:
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                            except NoSuchElementException:
                                return False
                            return True

                        for lst_handle in range(2,h2):
                        #for lst_handle in range(1,h2):
                            driver.switch_to.window(lst_window[lst_handle])
                            xpath2 = "//*[@id='create_button']"
                            xpath3="//*[@id='update_button']"
                            #css2 = '#create_button'
                            #css3 = '#update_button'
                            if check_exists_by_xpath(xpath2):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()
                                #driver.close()

                            elif check_exists_by_xpath(xpath3):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
                                #driver.close()

                           #if driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css2):
                            #    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css2).click()
                            #elif driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css3):
                             #   driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css3).click()

                            #if driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2) or driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3):
                             #   driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2 or xpath3).click()
                              #  driver.close()
                            #elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3):
                                #driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
                                #driver.close()





                #cont+=1
            #print(cont)



        #except ValueError:
        except Exception:
            if st == str(st):
                xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st + "')]"
                #cont1=0
                if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()  # Here new window will open
                    handles = driver.window_handles
                    h = len(handles)  # h=2

                    # print(handles)
                    for handle in range(1, h):
                        # for handle in range(h):

                        driver.switch_to.window(handles[handle])
                        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/input').click()
                        #time.sleep(5)
                        #driver.close()

                        lst_window = driver.window_handles
                        h2 = len(lst_window)  # h2=2
                        def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
                            try:
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                            except NoSuchElementException:
                                return False
                            return True
                        #for lst_handle in range(1, h2):
                        for lst_handle in range(2,h2):
                            driver.switch_to.window(lst_window[lst_handle])
                            xpath2 = "//*[@id='create_button']"
                            xpath3 = "//*[@id='update_button']"
                            if check_exists_by_xpath(xpath2):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()
                                #driver.close()

                            elif check_exists_by_xpath(xpath3):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
                                #driver.close()


"""
                            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()
                                driver.close()
                            elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
                                """
```

What's wrong with my code.
In excel i've n number of values(rows) in that only for the first value code is executing successfully. Rest of the values picking up, but

```
xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]"
                #cont = 0
                if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
```

After this code the control moving back Excel(for loop) and some some time it's throwing ValueError.

```
except Exception:
    if st == str(st):
        xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st + "')]"
        #cont1=0
```

Here throwing an exception as

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "m.py", line 53, in <module> if st == float(st): ValueError: could not convert string to float: '23' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Can anyone help me, Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload the full text of the error you are getting?  I'm a little confused what exactly the problem is.  Also, since you are having a problem with your xPath, could you upload the HTML or link to the URL?  Finally, where is `driver` defined?  For example if you are using Chrome you need to define the driver in this fashion:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/binary/chromedriver");`

Comment: On a second inspection I'm confused what you are trying to do.  Where are you opening the browser in the first place?  Selenium functions, like finding things by xPath, need to have opened a web browser as that is the only thing with which selenium can interact.

Comment: On top of path some code is there which I can't share

Comment: In any case, I don't think it will be possible to debug your xPath without the full HTML, or URL of the page(s).  Finally, could you paste the full text of the error(s) you are getting?

Comment: Didn't get any error. Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Second page HTML it's depends on the variable which is defined on st_string some times it'll be like  : <input class="t2" style="color:#000000;background-color:#FFCC00;" type="button" value="Update This Case"  onclick="javascript:popCaseUpdate(&quot;1615525&quot;, &quot;5336892096&quot;);">           And someother time     <input class="t2" type="button" value="Create New Case" onclick="javascript:popCaseCreate(&quot;1649059&quot;);">

Comment: Third page HTML sometimes :  <input id="update_button" class="t2" type="button" onclick="javascript:return(verifyUpdate());" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Update 5336892096&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"> and          <input id="create_button" class="t2" type="button" onclick="javascript:return(verifyCreate());" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Create New Case&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">

Comment: Next thing I notice is this line:

`driver.switch_to.window(handles[handle])#/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/input`

I don't think you want that xPath listed after you switch windows, just in the following line as it already is.

Comment: yes, that is commented. Are you asking me to remove it?

Comment: Doh, I forgot commenting syntax in python.  Obviously that is not affecting anything.

However I notice that neither of your example elements has a value of `Analyze` and both of your xPaths require that as far as I can see.  Am I missing something or could that be the/a problem?

`xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st + "')]"`

Comment: Analyze will be there for each and every st ot st_string

Comment: lst_window = driver.window_handles
                        h2 = len(lst_window) #h2=3

                        #for lst_handle in range(2,h2):
                        for lst_handle in range(1,h2):
                            driver.switch_to.window(lst_window[lst_handle])
                            xpath2 = "//*[@id='create_button']"
                            xpath3="//*[@id='update_button']"

                            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2):   after that control is Jumping to Except block which is not the correct flow.

Comment: The following steps has to perform :driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()
                                driver.close()
                            elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3):
                                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
                                driver.close()

Comment: "if driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2): after that control is Jumping to Except block which is not the correct flow"

wouldn't that indicate that the xpath is incorrect?  If so it would throw an `ElementNotFoundException` and jump to your `except`.   Again, it would be helpful to see the HTML of the page, I don't know any other way to troubleshoot an xpath.

Comment: HTML for that is : Third page HTML sometimes :  <input id="update_button" class="t2" type="button" onclick="javascript:return(verifyUpdate());" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Update 5336892096&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"> and          <input id="create_button" class="t2" type="button" onclick="javascript:return(verifyCreate());" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Create New Case&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">

Comment: So in your loop you are using `xpath2` on the first window, and `xpath3` on the second window?  If so, is it possible that `xpath2` is not found on the second window when it loops the second time?  This would, again, throw an `ElementNotFoundException`.  Again, this would be much easier to troubleshoot with the FULL HTML of the page.

Comment: No, in second window only  I'm checking for create or update button

Comment: So the second window also contains both buttons?

Comment: Either one(both won't contain).

Comment: So you just want to confirm that one of the two elements is found on each window?  See my answer below for an explanation of why I believe it is jumping to your `except` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your latest comment, it seems that the second window (at least) will not contain at least one of `"//*[@id='create_button']"` or `"//*[@id='update_button']"`.  This being the case, in the following block of code,

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()
    driver.close()
elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
    driver.close()
```

At least one of

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2):
```

or

```
elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3):
```

will throw an `ElementNotFoundException` sending you to your `except` block.

This is because executing `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` throws such an error any time that element is not located.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish or what your pages look like so I don't know what fix to make, but this seems to be the cause of your problem.  If you can provide more details on exactly what you're trying to do with this loop I might be able to suggest a fix.

On second thought, the following might work:

Add this import and function somewhere:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
try:
    webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
except NoSuchElementException:
    return False
return True
```

Then, change your original if block to:

```
if check_exists_by_xpath(xpath2):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()
    driver.close()
elif check_exists_by_xpath(xpath3):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
    driver.close()
```

---

EDIT This is pretty much what I was thinking.  Does it help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import xlrd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\tmou\PycharmProjects\Python\WebScraping\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.stew.cyz.com/st/st_main.php')
driver.switch_to.frame('ST_mainFrame')
emailElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/input')

# emailElem=browser.find_element_by_id('log_main')
# emailElem=browser.find_element_by_name("hpuser_id")
emailElem.send_keys('xyn@hyo.com')
# time.sleep(5)
passwordElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/p[1]/input')
passwordElem.send_keys('********')
passwd = passwordElem.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/p[2]/input').click()
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame('topFrame')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
'.menu > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(7) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').click()  # Reports
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame('ST_mainFrame')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
'div.menu_row:nth-child(16) > span:nth-child(3) > label:nth-child(2)').click()  # FTO

driver.switch_to.frame('fto_details')
time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html body table tbody tr td form table tbody tr td a img').click()  # search


path = r'C:\Users\tmou\PycharmProjects\Python\WebScraping\Book2.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for c in range(sheet.ncols):
    for r in range(sheet.nrows):
    st = (sheet.cell_value(r, c))
    try:
        if st == float(st):
            st_string = str(int(st))
            xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]"
            # cont = 0
            if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()  # Here new window will open
                handles = driver.window_handles
                h = len(handles)  # h=2

                # print(handles)
                for handle in range(1, h):
                    # for handle in range(h):

                    driver.switch_to.window(handles[handle])
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/input').click()
                    time.sleep(2)
                    driver.close()

                    lst_window = driver.window_handles
                    h2 = len(lst_window)  # h2=3

                    def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
                        try:
                            webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            return False
                        return True

                    # for lst_handle in range(2,h2):
                    for lst_handle in range(1, h2):
                        driver.switch_to.window(lst_window[lst_handle])
                        xpath2 = '//*[@id="create_button"]'
                        xpath3 = '//*[@id="update_button"]'


                        if check_exists_by_xpath(xpath2):
                            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()
                            driver.close()
                        elif check_exists_by_xpath(xpath3):
                            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()
                            driver.close()

            # cont+=1
        # print(cont)



    # except ValueError:
    except Exception:
        if st == str(st):
            xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st + "')]"
            # cont1=0
            if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()  # Here new window will open
                handles = driver.window_handles
                h = len(handles)  # h=2

                # print(handles)
                for handle in range(1, h):
                    # for handle in range(h):

                    driver.switch_to.window(
                        handles[handle])  # /html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/input
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/input').click()
                    # time.sleep(5)
                    driver.close()

                    lst_window = driver.window_handles
                    h2 = len(lst_window)  # h2=2

                    for lst_handle in range(2, h2):
                        if driver.switch_to.window(lst_window[lst_handle]):
                            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="create_button"]').click()
                            driver.close()
                        else:
                            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="update_button"]').click()
                            driver.close()
```

Comment: I'm confused about where to define check_exists_by_xpath(xpath) function. so posting my first half code also.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import xlrd
driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\tmou\PycharmProjects\Python\WebScraping\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://xyz.comt/st/st_main.php')
driver.switch_to.frame('ST_mainFrame')
emailElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/input')
emailElem.send_keys('xshdfg@xyz.com')

Comment: passwordElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/p[1]/input')
passwordElem.send_keys('#####')
passwd=passwordElem.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log_main"]/p[2]/input').click()
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame('topFrame')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.menu > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(7) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').click()#Reports
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame('ST_mainFrame')

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.menu_row:nth-child(16) > span:nth-child(3) > label:nth-child(2)').click() #FTO
driver.switch_to.frame('fto_details')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html body table tbody tr td form table tbody tr td a img').click()#search

Comment: It should work if you define it right above the `if check_exists_by_xpath(xpath2)`.  You will want the import statement at the top of the file with the other ones.

Could you please add that code to your question?  It is really hard to read in comments like this.

Comment: I think you can put the function declaration just about anywhere if I remember my python correctly.  For example above the `for c in range(sheet.ncols):` line

Comment: code has been added to the question. Now can you please check and let me know.

Comment: I added the full code with my suggested fix to my answer.  Does it help?

Comment: it's working for only one column(First) in the Excel. Rest of the columns code is not working. xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]"
                #cont = 0
                if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath): after that control is jumping to for c in range(sheet.ncols):

Comment: got the following error:          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tmou/PycharmProjects/Python/WebScraping/STaTS.py", line 53, in <module>
    if st == float(st):
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4C17461624'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
 File
"C:\Users\tmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line
410, in find_elements_by_xpath
return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: File "C:\Users\tmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\Users\tmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\tmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed

Comment: The problem with my example is that I've missed an indentation at this line:

`for r in range(sheet.nrows):`

I don't think there's an easy way for me to indent that entire block of code but that is probably why it is only doing one column.  As for your error message, it looks like your usage of `st == float(st):` because of the letters in the string.

Comment: Actually, st(variable) is taking the rest of values but xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]"
                #cont = 0
                if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath): after this aging jumping to excel.

Comment: Code has been updated. Only for first column it's working. I think it might be issue with driver.switch_to.window(). I'm i right?

Comment: I don’t know why it’s still not working. I’ll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: @MonikaKrishna I noticed you accepted my answer—is it working for you now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your current problem is simply that you are trying to convert a string with alphabetic characters to a float which would need strictly numerical values. Whatever data is on your excel sheet cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Excel contains the values like :  1615525
1652273
4C17461624
1649059     Xapth : xpath = "//input[@value='Analyze' and contains(@onclick,'" + st_string + "')]" will take strings only so i'm trying to convert them to string.

Comment: If you just want to convert them to string why don’t you simply use  st_string = str(st)?

Comment: I think one place you do, but you also have ‘st == float(st)’ on line 53 which I believe causes your current error.

Comment: Yes, because Excel values are integers and strings when we use that excel in your code INTEGERS will be treated as FLOATS so i'm trying them to convert INT and then STR . Directly i convert to STRINGS but .0 will be there at the end which i don't want.

Comment: #C.Peck Have you check it now.

Comment: Are you facing a new issue now?  If so I agree with @JeffC--your original issue has been addressed (and several more that followed) so you should open a new question with the latest version of your code and whatever error you are currently encountering. This is getting messy with my multiple answers and the long comment chains.